# Have Capybara screenshots saved to feature folder

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

When running tests with Capybara I'd like to save screenshots of failed steps to a feature specific folder. My current Capybara save path looks like:

`Capybara::save_path = "./screenshots"`

What I would want would be for it to save like

`Capybara::save_path = "./screenshots/<feature_name>`

I'm using Cucumber for my testing framework

Comment: How do you wish to determine the "feature_name"? What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, updated the question with details of the testing framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do it:

```
Capybara::save_path = "./screenshots"
Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:cucumber) do |example|
  "/#{example.feature.name.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//,'')}/screenshot_#{example.name.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//,'')}"
end
```

That results in nicely formatted screenshots where they are stored as
`screenshots/<feature>/<scenario>_2018-01-01`

Comment: Note: this requires the `capybara-screenshot` gem

Answer (score 0):

The way to write a parameter inside a path is the following one:

```
Capybara::save_path = "./screenshots/#{feature_name}"
```